# Why would I ever prefer ALGORITHM=COPY to ALGORITHM=INPLACE?

Tags: mysql, alter-table, ddl, online-operations

Since MySQL 5.6 introduced online DDL, the [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/alter-table.html) command can optionally have either `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` or `ALGORITHM=COPY` specified. The [overview of online DDL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html) notes that, by default, `INPLACE` is used wherever possible, and *implies* (without ever quite stating it) that the `INPLACE` algorithm is cheaper than the `COPY` one is.

So what reason would I ever have to specify `ALGORITHM=COPY` on an `ALTER TABLE` statement?

Comment: If you use COPY what happens to the indexes on the table?  Do you end up with defragmented indexes due to a fresh table being created and populated from scratch?

Comment: If COPY does populate from scratch then although it is a slow option the resulting table might perform better due to defragged indexes.

Comment: @DavePoole Nice theory, but I suspect it's off the mark since [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html) (which I believe has defragging indexes as a large part of its *purpose*) uses `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` as of MySQL 5.7.4. So I think it's the case that, yes, `COPY` *does* defrag indexes, but *so does `INPLACE`* (somehow), nullifying it as a potential advantage of `COPY`.

Comment: "InnoDB tables created before MySQL 5.6 do not support `ALTER TABLE ... ALGORITHM=INPLACE` for tables that include temporal columns (DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP) and have not been rebuilt using `ALTER TABLE ... ALGORITHM=COPY`"...[Limitations of Online DDL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-limitations.html)

Answer (score 24):

Yes, there are cases when you may specify `COPY`, but it would be for other reasons than performance.

It is important to understand that MySQL introduced new feature - Online DLL processing in version 5.6. It did not remove offline processing. So there is a need to differentiate between these 2 modes:

1. Some operations still work in Offline mode only. See Table 15.10, “[Summary of Online Status for DDL Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html#innodb-online-ddl-summary-grid)” for a list of the DDL operations that can or cannot be performed in-place.
2. Operations in Online and Offline modes have slightly different behavior, so you can choose "old" one for compatibility reasons.

Some examples (please suggest more):

1. InnoDB tables created before MySQL 5.6 do not support `ALTER TABLE ... ALGORITHM=INPLACE` for tables that include temporal columns (`DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`) and have not been rebuilt using `ALTER TABLE ... ALGORITHM=COPY`. In this case, an `ALTER TABLE ... ALGORITHM=INPLACE` operation returns error.
2. `ADD PRIMARY KEY` clause in `COPY mode` silently converts `NULL` to default values for that data type (0 for INT,  empty string for varchar), whereas `IN_PLACE` does not do that.

> With the ALGORITHM=COPY clause, the operation succeeds despite the
>   presence of NULL values in the primary key columns; the data is
>   silently changed, which could cause problems.

Another reason to prefer `COPY`:

> Operations for which you specify ALGORITHM=COPY or old_alter_table=1,
>   to force the table-copying behavior if needed for precise
>   backward-compatibility in specialized scenarios.

Although MySQL manual doesn't talk about actual scenarios, you can imagine some. E.g. developer relied on table being locked during `ALTER INDEX` operation so table is read-only or fully locked and there is a process that reads static table during index rebuild.

Comment: I think people also tend to confuse `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` with "this is Online DDL and won't lock the database", when in fact, they actually want to use `LOCK=NONE`.

Answer (score 3):

@Stoleg probably has the best answer, but here is another one.  It's an educated guess that the developers left `=COPY` in as an escape hatch in case there was a serious bug in `=INLINE`.  This would let users continue to use `ALTER` even if the new feature is broken.

I have seen things like this (in flags, `sql_mode`, `my.cnf` settings, etc) over the years.  The intent of the new release is clearly to bring out the new, better, feature.

Optimization flags fall into this category, but there is even more reason to hang onto the previous actions -- the Optimizer will always "do it wrong" sometimes; there are simply too many possibilities.

Comment: Why would you call it "escape hatch" rather than "backward compatibility"? Though there may not be much difference ;)

Comment: I would say "backward compatibility" if I needed the same code to run on both versions.  But then I would worry about whether the new syntax was recognized by the old version.

Answer (score -1):

In versions of MySQL that support InnoDB tablespace encryption, when you alter a table to add encryption, the alteration is done using the copy algorithm out of necessity.